# Remove Automated Response from Exchange 2010 mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

An automated response was setup on a users mailbox that is only sent when their OoO is enabled. This is sent as well as the OoO message.

How can I remove this?

I have checked the OoO settings, Rules, Add-Ins, Transport Rules on the server and cannot find anything relating to this message. There is no third party software installed on the Exchange server (2010) other than Kaspersky Security 8. The message is still sent when their Outlook is closed and their PC is turned off, so it has to be something on the server right?

Does anyone have any ideas how this may have been configured?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an Outlook Rule. Try to check it

[Out of Office](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/484-outlook-2010-how-to-set-out-of-office-in-outlook-2010.html)

What is the output of

```
Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration yourUser
```

Comment: It is not an Outlook rules, non in there. The OoO reply is delivered AS WELL as the mystery email, the settings on the servers powershell just reflect what the user has input on their Outlook OoO settings.

Comment: This is really strange. Do you have any scripts or GPO's that maybe turns on the OoO when the user turns off his computer?? You can check with rsop.msc. What says `Get-MailBoxAutoreplyConfiguration` if users computer is off? Is then the OoO enabled?